# "No globally defined name" when trying to removed a named_range using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a simple Excel sheet which needs to update a named range in the sheet.  Since openpyxl doesn't do this directly, I need to remove the old range and then create a new range (based on the old range):

```
rng = wb.get_named_range('range')
wb.remove_named_range(rng)
wb.create_named_range('range', ws0, '$A$21:$A$' + str(highRow+1))
```

There is already a range in the workbook with the name "range", the worksheet I'm trying to apply the range to is ws0, and highRow is just the max row of ws0.

When I run this i get the following error at wb.remove_named_range(rng):

> KeyError: "No globally defined name
>   \nParameters:\ncustomMenu=None, workbookParameter=None,
>   shortcutKey=None, description=None, vbProcedure=None, xlm=None,
>   publishToServer=None, hidden=None, name='range', localSheetId=None,
>   attr_text='Ranges!$A$21:$A$22', functionGroupId=None, function=None,
>   statusBar=None, help=None, comment=None"

Am I not referencing the named range correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete a range by it's name:

`del wb.defined_names['range']`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Now I'm not sure what `remove_named_range` is for, but thanks!

Comment: It's legacy code that will disappear at some point. The initial implementation treated all defined names as if they were cell ranges but this is not the case and it's also not very Pythonic.